# Convert raw AAC data to PCM data via ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac, pcm

I have a system which is transmitting raw AAC data via TCP (no ADTS frame/header).  Each "packet" is prefixed with enough information for me to determine the length of the raw data.  I also have the sample rate (8k) and channel (mono) information up front.

I'm trying to figure out away to convert the RAW AAC data to PCM so it can be consumed by the audio subsystem of the platform (right now I'm playing around on MacOS, but I intend to use a Raspberry Pi at some stage - this part is immediately beyond the scope of the question).

Essentially, the aim is to do this in real time, avoiding writing data out to a file, instead writing the PCM data to the platforms audio system buffer (via the languages API).

I'm looking for away to make use of ffmpeg libraries directly (leaning towards Java, making use of https://github.com/Manevolent/ffmpeg4j possibly, but I'll take C).

So far, all my research has found solutions focused on ADTS frames or converting files, which is not suitable (at least from my limited experience) for the task.

Is there away to convert Raw AAC data to PCM via the ffmpegs libraries (not CLI)?

Comment: As `ffmpeg` can process `.aac` files, which is raw AAC frames with an ADTS header, I would assume that you can do that using the ffmpeg libraries as well. As you know sample rate and channel count, making an ADTS header for the libraries, if needed, shouldn't be a problem, either. Have you actually tried doing it?

Comment: I'm a complete noob when it comes to ffmpeg libraries, so I'm basically starting from scratch and looking for some points to move me in a direction

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2402671/3554119), found by googling for "example program ffmpeg libraries". I don't think the Q&A on this site is a good format for "please guide me how to use ffmpeg libraries".

Comment: @dirkt I appreciate the point, but you have to start somewhere and from personal experience, it's much better easier to find an answer when you know what you're looking for ;)